# Integrating mobile app and mobile web

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, coronasdk

Currently I am developing an app in corona sdk. It is still very early in the development stage so I can change the IDE or SDK if needed to achieve my goal.

I wish to create an app that can be played on multiple platforms(mainly ios and android) and I eventually want the users to be able to use the browser to continue playing at home with their progress saved. It is a simple app and could probably be recreated in html. They will have to login their accounts in order to play

How do i go about to achieve this? Should I complete my app in corona first, and then recreate the app in html and php and link the database to it separately or is there a specific development kit I could use that has this ability. Also, I am new to the development scene, how do I detect if the user is logged in a particular platform as I realize if they are logged in, in multiple places and give multiple entries it may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to the development scene then you should continue developing with Corona.
Corona doesn't povide any web port but I know Unity does.
I think first you should complete your game for mobile platforms and if it will have success you can port it to web.

You can read this:
http://www.graphic-buffet.com/2012/06/indie-game-development-where-start/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try phonegap (http://phonegap.com/). I have never used it, I just know that it exists, so do some research to see if it would be a good fit. This might allow you to create the app once for both browsers and mobile.